# PHP is failing to save Base64 string file in a server

Tags: php

My PHP script is failing to save an image file in 000webhost server. Here is my code:

```
...

$decodedImage = base64_decode($image_encoded);
$mod_image_name = str_replace(' ', '', $image_name);
$path = "images/" . $mod_image_name . ".jpg";       // 'images' folder is inside 'public_html'
$is_written = file_put_contents($path, $decodedImage);

// to verify variables using MySQL
$query = "INSERT INTO `id2-mydb`.`my_table`
(`id`, `image_name`, `image_code`) 
VALUES (NULL, '$image_name', '$image_encoded')";

mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

The string image `$image_encoded` is coming from Android-processed `Base64.encodeToString`, and Android side and data transfer is working fine. When `$image_encoded` inserted into MySQL database, I can copy-paste the code in base64decode.org and it produces the needed image.

My 000webhost File Manager folders looks like this:

- public_html

  - php_folder
  - images

And FTP transfer is ON.

I'm not sure what I'm missing in the process and why it's not saving an image in routed folder at all, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so - which part is failing ~ saving to database or saving the image to disk?

Comment: @RamRaider, saving the image to disk is failing

Comment: I would try using the full path rather than a relative one as a first test

Comment: @RamRaider, I've used several options to assign the path, none appears to work so far. Do you mind to give me a fresh look/idea on how your version of full path should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$path = __DIR__ . "/../images/" . $mod_image_name . ".jpg";
```

Since images is a sibling of php_folder and I assume this script is in the PHP folder.

You should also check the return value for success, and make sure the web process has write permission to `images`